# ViewPager indicator scrolling up/down with whole page

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, scrollview

I've made `Activity` with `ViewPager` and I also have adapter for it and `Fragment` which is displayed by `ViewPager`.
 Whole `Fragment` (in XML) is inside `ScrollView`. When I'm scrolling page up and down the indicator doesn't scroll with whole layout. 
I know the reason why this is happening (indicator is inside Activity layout and ScrollView is inside Fragment XML file).
 I need some help or advice how to make it scroll or any other solution how to avoid that because indicator at "start position" is looking good but when I scroll down it covers part of text.
I know it is possible because I've seen it on Instagram but I don't know how to achieve this.
Let me provide some code:
**Activity with ViewPager:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Album.AlbumPagerActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/album_pager_fab_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:alpha=".7"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/CKBrownie"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/back_ico"
        android:tint="@color/CKGold"
        android:translationZ="0dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/CKBrownie" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/album_pager_fab_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:alpha=".7"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/CKBrownie"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/forward_ico"
        android:tint="@color/CKGold"
        android:translationZ="0dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/CKBrownie" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/album_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/album_view_pager"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_360sdp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Fragment:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroudmck">
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Album.PhotoFragment">


    <com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
        android:id="@+id/photo_pager_image"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_240sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_360sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/photo_pager_image_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_24sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_16sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_24sdp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Image title"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/photo_pager_image" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/underline_photo_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_2sdp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_22sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_22sdp"
        android:background="@color/CKGold"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/photo_pager_image_title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/photo_pager_image_technique"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_24sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_24sdp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_18sdp"
        android:text="Additional info about image"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/underline_photo_fragment" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/photo_pager_image_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_24sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_16sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_24sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_2sdp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_18sdp"
        android:text="Long image description (because of this TextView I had to make it scrollable)"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/photo_pager_image_technique" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Adapter:**

```
public class AlbumViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private int number;

    public AlbumViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int number) {
        super(fm);
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        PhotoFragment pf;
        Bundle bundle;

        switch (i) {

            case 0:
                bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("num", i);
                bundle.putInt(Constants.NUMBER, number);
                pf = new PhotoFragment();
                pf.setArguments(bundle);
                return pf;
            case 1:
                bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("num", i);
                bundle.putInt(Constants.NUMBER, number);
                pf = new PhotoFragment();
                pf.setArguments(bundle);
                return pf;
            case 2:
                bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("num", i);
                bundle.putInt(Constants.NUMBER, number);
                pf = new PhotoFragment();
                pf.setArguments(bundle);
                return pf;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Object obj = super.instantiateItem(container, position);

        return obj;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

}
```

Instagram app has a `ViewPager` with `indicator` placed below a photo but above a text and when I navigate between "pages" the text and the photo are changing but when I scroll page up/down the `indicator` move with whole page up and down.
 Maybe it's a problem with my indicator placement? But when I try to put it inside the `Fragment` I won't be able to attach it to my `ViewPager` which is created inside `Activity`

Comment: Indicator is completely independent of view pager fragment. It shouldn't scroll with fragment. I tried this code but couldn't replicate the issue.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it shouldn't now. What I'm trying to do is to make it scroll with whole page. For now I don't see it possible to make it happen because as you said: indicator is completely independent of fragment.